# Enabling Push Notifications for a Parse iOS application -- having trouble setting it up

Tags: ios, parsing, push-notification, xcode5

I have followed the [Parse guide](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) on how to set this up twice now, but it isn't working.

1. In my Apple Developer Account, under Identifiers, I modified the App ID to use "Push Notifications".
2. I followed the instructions and created a SSL certificate and installed it to my Macbook keychain
3. I exported the SSL certificate from my macbook keychain (with no password) and imported it into the "Push Notification" settings page in Parse.
4. I added this code to the `appdelegate.m`, at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method after my Parse registration key.

> ```
> [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
>                                                 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
>                                                 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
> ```

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
  [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
  [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

---

I simply cannot figure out what is not working.

My provisioning profiles have worked fine, I've been working on the app for a few months now (local development and TestFlight testing).

I'm not sure if maybe the Parse tutorial is out of date? Maybe it is done differently now?
Can anyone provide any insight?

Very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you seeing installation objects in your Parse.com data browser?  Are you running on a real device?

Comment: Don't forget you have to **redo the provisioning profiles** to make them "pick up" the new, um, information about the push cert.  (It's incredibly hard to keep this straight in one's head, heh!)  The Parse tutorial is perfect, up to date, and works perfectly.

Comment: (It's not unlike, you know when you happen to add a device, you have to redo the certs/profiles -- err, whichever one that is  :)  )

Comment: PS.  don't forget. (once you get it working)  there's a hell of a lot to be said for not registering for Push **UNTIL** you have fully logged in the user as a PFUser.  it's harmless to do so, but it will result in pointless empty entries in your Installations on the dashboard.  Note this subtle discussion .. https://www.parse.com/questions/iospush-confirming-are-blank-devicetoken-entries-in-installation-totally-harmless

Comment: @logan - This is what it was. I was running on the iOS simulator, but as soon as I switched over to running it on my device...it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run on a real device instead of the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set app ID and client key before you set the device token:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APP_ID
              clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];
```

Comment: true, but nothing would work unless he does that first anyway.  I'm guessing OP was caught out by the annoying "you have to 'again redo' all your certs/profiles" gotchya....